# Are intestinal and pancreatic lipases different?

Tags: zoology, human-physiology, digestive-system

For explaining the action pancreatic lipase, my book wrote this equation:-

$$fat\space particles + lipase\rightarrow fatty\space acid + glycerol + lipase$$

But for intestinal lipase, my book has a different equation:-

$$fat\space particles + lipase\rightarrow monoglyceride + fatty\space acid$$

So, did my book make a mistake or are intestinal and pancreatic lipases different?

Comment: Does food enter the pancreas? Where do pancreatic enzymes act?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pancreatic lipase and intestinal lipase are almost same in their functions. ***In the intestine, the name of the lipase is a triacylglycerol acyl hydrolase it also called colipase dependent lipase or Pancreatic lipase,  Free fatty acids, and 2-monoacylglycerol are the primary products of lipid digestion in the jejunum***. and Pancreatic Lipase also produces Free fatty acids and 2- monoacylglycerol.

so we can say that both enzymes are almost same and produce the same products.

Sources Lippincott's Illustrated Reviews Biochemistry 5th edition Chapter 15